# How to rbind multiple matrices into one big matrix

Tags: r, matrix, rbind

I defined a function to process each csv file and it returns a matrix. I would like to use this function in a for loop to process all the files and combine all the data into one big matrix. But it seems this code does not work.

```
filenames=dir()

bigMatrix = processEachCSV(filenames[1])

for (i in 2:length(filenames1)) {
  x = processEachCSV(filenames[i])
  bigMatrix=rbind[bigMatrix,x]
}
```

I guess it is because I can not rbind x and bigMatrix and assign it to bigMatrix itself?

What shall I do instead?

The processEachCSV functions is like this:

```
processEachCSV <- function (filename){

  x = read.table(filename, header=F, sep=',', fileEncoding='UTF-8')
  x$V4=as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]",'', as.character(x$V4)))
  x$V5=as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]",'', as.character(x$V5)))
  x$V6=substr(filename, 1, nchar(filename)-4)
  colnames(x)=c('DateTime','Site','AQI','PM25','PM10','City')
  x=as.matrix(x)
  return (x)
}
```

Comment: Read all the files in as a `list` and then use `do.call(rbind, yourList)`.

Comment: You realize the to use `rbind`, you need to use `()` and not `[]`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic approach would be something like:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.csv))
```

Customize the `read.csv` part with whatever you actually do with your `processEachCSV` function (if that is indeed a function).

---

Alternatively, you can look at some of the `rbind_list` function from "dplyr" or the `rbindlist` function from "data.table", both of which are more efficient than `do.call(rbind, ...)`. The result would not be a `matrix` in those cases, but you can convert it to a matrix quite easily.

Comment: Yes, the processEachCSV is indeed a function. So I tried this 'do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, processEachCSV()))' but it seems the filename were not passed to the processEachCSV function.

Comment: I also tried to convert filenames from a character vector to list, by using do.call(rbind, lapply(as.list(filenames'), processEachCSV())). Did not work either.

Comment: @user3768495, you should try `do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, processEachCSV))`. Don't add the `()` to `processEachCSV`. However, without knowing what exactly `processEachCSV` does, it would be hard for me to ensure that what I'm suggesting would work. Also, do all the files have the same number of columns?

Comment: I tried not using () too and still not working. All the files have 6 columns, I have checked...I updated my question to show you the function. Thank you!

Comment: @user3768495, not related to the problem, I suppose, but why are you using a `matrix` when your columns include different data types? Why aren't you using a `data.frame`?

Comment: I think the problem is in the part of lapply(filename, processEachCSV). Got an error message: ' Error in read.table(filename, header = F, sep = ",", fileEncoding = "UTF-8") : 
  no lines available in input '

Comment: by the way, how did you make some words highlighted in gray?

Comment: @user3768495, use "backticks" `\``

Comment: I finally realized that it is because some of my files are empty.`filenames <- filenames[file.info(filenames)$size > 1]` helped me out!